# Basic JavaScript quiz app

Tags: javascript, jquery, quiz

I struggled my way through the first quiz and here are the results.  Since I have some experience in jQuery I really wanted to use only vanilla JavaScript.  I know the code is pretty choppy and there is most likely a lot of room for improvement.

How can I make this code more succinct? What are some better practices that i can implement?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hb8te6wx/).

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="quiz">
         <h1>How well do you know Matt</h1>
    </div>
    <input type='submit' id='myBtn' value='' />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var allQuestions = [
{
    question: "What is Matt favorite color?",
    choices: ["Blue", "Black", "Yellow", "Blank", "Clear" ],
    correctAnswer: 4
},
{
    question: "Who is Matt's Favorite fiction Author?",
    choices: ["Brennan Manning", "JD Salinger", "Stephen King", "Jack Kerouac"],
    correctAnswer: 3
},
{
    question: "What is Matt's favorite food?",
    choices: ["Pizza", "Wings", "Mexican", "Rally's"],
    correctAnswer: 0
}
];

var submitBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var currentQuestion = 0;
var tally = 0;

var quizForm = document.getElementById('quiz');
var question;
var choices;
var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('radioOption');
var index = 0;

function firstFunc() {
    if (currentQuestion === 0) {
        submitBtn.value = "Start Quiz";
    }
}

function askQuestion () {
    choices = allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices;
    question = allQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
    if (currentQuestion < allQuestions.length) {
        submitBtn.value = "Next";
        quizForm.innerHTML = "<h1>" + question + "</h1>";
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            quizForm.innerHTML += "<label><input type='radio' name='radioOption' value='" + choices[i] + "'/>" + choices[i] + "</label>";
        }
        if (currentQuestion == allQuestions.length - 1) {
            submitBtn.value = "Submit";
        } else if (currentQuestion > allQuestions.length - 1) {
            calcQuiz();
        }
    }
}

function lookForChecked() {

    if (radioButtons.length > 1) {

            var checked = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
            var selection = radioButtons[i];

             if (selection.checked) {

                var index = [i];
                if (i === allQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer) {
                    tally++;

                }
                if (currentQuestion < allQuestions.length -1) {
                    currentQuestion++;

                } else {
                    console.log('you have ended the quiz');
                    calcQuiz();
                   return false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($('input[name="radioOption"]:checked').length < 1) {
            alert('Please Make a Selection');
        }
    }
        askQuestion();
}

function calcQuiz() {
    quizForm.innerHTML = "<h1>You have finished the quiz</h1><p class='total'>You scored a total of " + tally + " out of " + allQuestions.length + "</h1>";
    submitBtn.remove();
}
window.onload = firstFunc();
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', lookForChecked);
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I changed the link to your fiddle to a forked version using the jsfiddle option for jQuery version and removing the unused html.

Comment: Totally fine.  First time posting to both jsfiddle and stackexchange.  I suppose that is why jQuery was not working inherently when I did not include the link/html?

Comment: Are you sure this code works? It seems that `askQuestion()` isn't invoked on page load. So the first question and its options aren't displayed

Comment: I have an event handler on submitBtn.  askQuestion() is not invoked on the page load.  It is not invoked until the submitBtn is clicked, which directly invokes lookForChecked(), which directly invokes askQuestion()

Comment: Why so complex? "Start Quiz" text is only used at the start until the button is clicked. So you can put it in HTML, then it will be replaced once `lookForChecked` is invoked. In this case you don't need to check `radioButtons.length` in `lookForChecked()`.

Comment: But if I don't check for `radioBtuttons.length` then I get the "Please make a a selection" alert after the initial click.  I see that I can use `&&` and add it to `if ($('input[name="radioOption"]:checked').length`.

Answer (score 3):

## Design

You could remake this using [Object-Oriented-Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). For example, you could make a `Question` object, like this.

```
function Question(description, choices, correctChoiceIndex) {
    this.description = description;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.correctChoiceIndex = correctChoiceIndex;
}
```

You could then extend it with some methods, like `askQuestion`. For example, you could do something like this *(Using `prompt` and `alert` because I'm on mobile.)*

```
Question.prototype.askQuestion = function() {
    return prompt("Choices:\n" + this.choices.join("\n"));
}
```

You could then supply an additional method, `checkAnswer`, to see if the user got the answer correct.

```
Question.prototype.checkAnswer = function() {
    if(parseInt(this.askQuestion(), 10) === this.correctChoiceIndex) {
        alert("You got the question right!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, wrong answer.");
    }
}
```

---

## Nitpicks

Some of your naming is not great. For example, `firstFunc` is an awful name for a function. It doesn't describe the purpose of the function in any way.

Preferably, names for variables/functions/classes should exhibit the following characteristics:

- Describe the variable/function/class in detail.
- Not have unnecessary abbreviations.
- Not be too short.
- Not be too long. *(Unless you're programming in [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c).)*

Most of your variable names exhibit these characteristics, I just saw a few, like `submitBtn` that could be expanded to something like `submitButton`.

Moving on, I saw this line I your code:

```
var index = [i];
```

It isn't used anywhere in it's scope, and even if it was used, it would serve no purpose at this point.

Finally, when using the increment, `++`, and decrement, `--` operators, [remember the differences between how they're placed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript).

Comment: Definitely the most exciting part of programming to me is designing Objects to connect and form a solution.